# Apache returning malformed header from script for Perl CGI script

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I am running a perl script on an Apache httpd server and intermittently I get 500 Internal Server Error.

When I check the error log , I see below error :

```
Mon Feb 22 15:04:25 2021] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx ] malformed header from script. Bad header=Can I override this?: test.cgi
```

Can someone please let me know what could have went wrong ?

Comment: Cross-posted to /r/perl https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/m2mbve/apache_returning_malformed_header_from_script_for/

Answer (score 1):

This first text that a CGI program should print to `STDOUT` is the CGI headers (which will probably include `Content-type:`).

It seems that under some circumstances, your program prints the string "Can I override this?" before those headers. The web server tries to parse that string as a header, fails and throws an error.

Look at your code, find out why it is printing that string and either stop it from doing so or ensure that the correct headers are printed first.

Without seeing your code, it's hard to be much more help.